Expected scalar type Long but found Int error while using tune on llama 3
When im trying to use Llama3-8B tune guide from :
https://pytorch.org/torchtune/0.1/tutorials/llama3.html
it gave me this error :
W0608 08:41:38.766000 10904 torch\distributed\elastic\multiprocessing\redirects.py:27] NOTE: Redirects are currently not supported in Windows or MacOs.
INFO:torchtune.utils.logging:Running LoRAFinetuneRecipeSingleDevice with resolved config:

batch_size: 2
checkpointer:
  _component_: torchtune.utils.FullModelMetaCheckpointer
  checkpoint_dir: D:\Hugging_Tune_Model\llama\original
  checkpoint_files:
  - consolidated.00.pth
  model_type: LLAMA3
  output_dir: D:\Hugging_Tune_Model\llama\original
  recipe_checkpoint: null
compile: false
dataset:
  _component_: torchtune.datasets.alpaca_cleaned_dataset
  train_on_input: true
device: cpu
dtype: bf16
enable_activation_checkpointing: true
epochs: 1
gradient_accumulation_steps: 64
log_every_n_steps: null
loss:
  _component_: torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss
lr_scheduler:
  _component_: torchtune.modules.get_cosine_schedule_with_warmup
  num_warmup_steps: 100
max_steps_per_epoch: null
metric_logger:
  _component_: torchtune.utils.metric_logging.DiskLogger
  log_dir: /tmp/lora_finetune_output
model:
  _component_: torchtune.models.llama3.lora_llama3_8b
  apply_lora_to_mlp: false
  apply_lora_to_output: false
  lora_alpha: 16
  lora_attn_modules:
  - q_proj
  - v_proj
  lora_rank: 8
optimizer:
  _component_: torch.optim.AdamW
  lr: 0.0003
  weight_decay: 0.01
output_dir: /tmp/lora_finetune_output
profiler:
  _component_: torchtune.utils.profiler
  enabled: false
resume_from_checkpoint: false
seed: null
shuffle: true
tokenizer:
  _component_: torchtune.models.llama3.llama3_tokenizer
  path: D:\Hugging_Tune_Model\llama\original/tokenizer.model

DEBUG:torchtune.utils.logging:Setting manual seed to local seed 3148683848. Local seed is seed + rank = 3148683848 + 0
Writing logs to \tmp\lora_finetune_output\log_1717823498.txt
INFO:torchtune.utils.logging:Model is initialized with precision torch.bfloat16.
INFO:torchtune.utils.logging:Tokenizer is initialized from file.
INFO:torchtune.utils.logging:Optimizer and loss are initialized.
INFO:torchtune.utils.logging:Loss is initialized.
Downloading readme: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 11.6k/11.6k [00:00<?, ?B/s]
Downloading data: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 44.3M/44.3M [00:08<00:00, 5.16MB/s]
Generating train split: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████| 51760/51760 [00:00<00:00, 62663.60 examples/s]
INFO:torchtune.utils.logging:Dataset and Sampler are initialized.
INFO:torchtune.utils.logging:Learning rate scheduler is initialized.
  0%|                                                                                        | 0/25880 [19:50<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\tune.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torchtune\_cli\tune.py", line 49, in main
    parser.run(args)
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torchtune\_cli\tune.py", line 43, in run
    args.func(args)
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torchtune\_cli\run.py", line 179, in _run_cmd
    self._run_single_device(args)
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torchtune\_cli\run.py", line 93, in _run_single_device
    runpy.run_path(str(args.recipe), run_name="__main__")
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 286, in run_path
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 98, in _run_module_code
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\recipes\lora_finetune_single_device.py", line 510, in <module>
    sys.exit(recipe_main())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torchtune\config\_parse.py", line 50, in wrapper
    sys.exit(recipe_main(conf))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\recipes\lora_finetune_single_device.py", line 505, in recipe_main
    recipe.train()
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\recipes\lora_finetune_single_device.py", line 453, in train
    loss = self._loss_fn(logits, labels)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 1185, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\por\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 3086, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Int

these are the steps that i followed from tutorial :
1.pip install torch
2.pip install tune
3.tune download meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B --output-dir D:\Hugging_Tune_Model\llama --hf-token XXXXXX
4.tune run lora_finetune_single_device --config llama3/8B_lora_single_device checkpointer.checkpoint_dir=D:\Hugging_Tune_Model\llama\original tokenizer.path=D:\Hugging_Tune_Model\llama\original/tokenizer.model checkpointer.output_dir=D:\Hugging_Tune_Model\llama\original device="c

ive tried the tutorial from pytorch site.
also there where a guide in youtube with this link :
https://youtu.be/7euBTCT0S2Q
and i followed exactly the same steps but couldnt the pass the tune run process
